# How to replace a string in the host file using batch?

Tags: batch-file, edit, hosts, hosts-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to find and replace an IP address in the hosts file.

I did a bit of research and found this, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the final echo of "Done." but it doesn't work.

```
@echo off

REM Set a variable for the Windows hosts file location
set hostpath=%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc
set hostfile=hosts

REM Make the hosts file writable
attrib -r %hostpath%\%hostfile%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set string=%hostpath%\%hostfile%

REM set the string you wish to find
set find=OLD IP

REM set the string you wish to replace with
set replace=NEW IP
call set string=%%string:!find!=!replace!%%
echo %string%

REM Make the hosts file un-writable
attrib +r %hostpath%\%hostfile%

echo Done.
```

Comment: Are you running the batch in Vista and Above? if so, try running with Admin rights.

Comment: it's being ran in windows xp or older, thanks though

Comment: That code doesn't actually open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

REM Set a variable for the Windows hosts file location
set "hostpath=%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc"
set "hostfile=hosts"

REM Make the hosts file writable
attrib -r -s -h "%hostpath%\%hostfile%"

REM set the string you wish to find
set find=OLD IP
REM set the string you wish to replace with
set replace=NEW IP

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%hostpath%\%hostfile%"') do (
set "string=%%a"
set "string=!string:%find%=%replace%!"
>> "newfile.txt" echo !string!
)

move /y "newfile.txt" "%hostpath%\%hostfile%"

REM Make the hosts file un-writable - not necessary.
attrib +r "%hostpath%\%hostfile%"

echo Done.
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is just trying to replace the values in the filename, not in the contents of the file.

You need to change the code in order to find and replace inside the content of the file.

To achieve this, you need to (1) read the file (2) find and replace the string and (3) write back

1. you have to read the file. Use the `FOR` command. Read `HELP FOR` and try the following code.

   ```
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%hostpath%\%hostfile%) do (
     echo %%a
   )
   ```
2. find and replace

   ```
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%hostpath%\%hostfile%) do (
     set string=%%a
     set string=!string:%find%=%replace%!
     echo !string!
   )
   ```
3. you have to write the results back to the file. Redirect the output of the echo to a temporary file and then replace the original file with the temporary file

   ```
   echo. >%temp%\hosts
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%hostpath%\%hostfile%) do (
     set string=%%a
     set string=!string:%find%=%replace%!
     echo !string! >>%temp%\hosts
   )
   copy %temp%\hosts %hostpath%\%hostfile%
   ```

Comment: The values will never appear in the path\filename - it is inside the file that they appear.

Comment: that was exactly what I was trying to say... that the code you provide does not look inside the file contents. My answer provides the code to look and replace *inside* the file content.

Comment: To use variable referance with ! you have to set `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Answer (score -1):

This will work.

```
call set newstring=%string:%find%=%replace%%
```

Assign the resultant value to a new string.