# How to search strings or numbers and replace them using batch scripting in a windows host file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been trying to create a batch code where I can search for an IP and a domain name in a windows host file `C:\Windows\Systems32\drivers\etc\host`.

I've already created a simple search function, listed below:

```
@echo off
set hostpath=%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

echo type the ip add or domain
set /p domain=
find "%domain%" %hostpath%

pause
```

I need more help with searching and replacing strings found within the host file because:

```
findstr /x /c:"%domain%" %hostpath%
```

does not return anything - empty output.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16208429/2152082

Comment: `findstr /x` means "complete line does match exactly" So it would give you only lines, that contain `%domain%` only. I think, you meant `/i` (ignore capitalization) instead?

Comment: And don't forget to run your script as administrator and to disable your antivirus because it will prevent you from writing in the (protected) hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

for the find command, if it does find the file the %errorlevel% will be zero (0). So you can use

```
if %errorlevel%==0 ren file newfile
```